# Kenshi First Puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

[image]

The above puzzle is from https://kenshi.io/docs/puzzles/1, which says that there is a key hidden in the image, which would allow withdrawal of prize money from a wallet. However the [wallet](https://kenshi.io/tools?address=0xBFE5C7dA985f8d3Ff689A4608436402dfF647B4F) is empty, so the competition is effectively over and there is no prize money left. How can the puzzle be solved?

Comment: We don't allow questions from ongoing competitions... *but* it seems that this competition is not ongoing - the prize fund has already been cleaned out.